# scroll to element not working in appium driver

Tags: javascript, scroll, automation, appium

scroll to element not working in **appium** driver.
Is there any javascript which works similar as

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", getWebDriver().findElement(locator));
```

for webdriver.
We are using

```
driver.context("WEBVIEW_" + applicationId);
```

instead of **uiautomator**.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use touchActions in appium to scroll like this :

```
TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
action.scroll(element, 10, 100);
action.perform();
```

or using giving reference to 2 elements as :

```
TouchAction().press(el0).moveTo(el1).release();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
((FindsByAndroidUIAutoamtor<?>)(driver).find_element_by_android_uiautomator('new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains("**Expected text**").instance(0))');
```

For more info about uiautomators refer https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiScrollable

Comment: This does not work for as we are using Webview
driver.context("WEBVIEW_" + applicationId);